# Wcf won't save item to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I have an issue with creating a new item in the database. I have created a Wcf service that should be consumed by a MVC client. I created an Entity Data Model in my Wcf service (BazaEntities) and I have defined a create method which creates a new employee in EmployeeTable:

```
public bool createEmp(Employee employee)
    {
        using (BazaEntities ben = new BazaEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                EmployeeTable etn = new EmployeeTable();
                etn.EmpName = employee.Name;
                etn.EmpLastName= employee.LastName;
                etn.EmpAddress = employee.Address;
                etn.City= employee.City;
                etn.RoleID = employee.RoleID;
                ben.EmployeeTables.Add(etn);
                ben.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

In my MVC client I have a controller for the service:

```
public class EmpManController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult IndexEmp()
    {
        EmpManServiceClient emsc = new EmpManServiceClient();
        ViewBag.listEmployees = emsc.findAllEmp();
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CreateEmp()
    {
        return View("CreateEmp");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateEmp(EmpManViewModel emvm)
    {
        EmpManServiceClient emsc = new EmpManServiceClient();
        emsc.createEmp(emvm.Employee);
        return RedirectToAction("IndexEmp");
    }
}
```

And a EmpManServiceClient class that has all the methods from the Wcf service defined, including the create method:

```
public bool createEmp(Employee employee)
    {
        try
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Employee));
            MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
            ser.WriteObject(mem, employee);
            string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mem.ToArray(), 0, (int)mem.Length);
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
            webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            webClient.UploadString(BASE_URL + "createemp", "POST", data);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

My index view looks like this:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>IndexEmp</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="@Url.Action("CreateEmp", "EmpMan")">Add new employee</a>
    <br /><br />
    <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>LastName</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>RoleID</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach(var employee in ViewBag.listEmployees)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@employee.Id</td>
                <td>@employee.Name</td>
                <td>@employee.LastName</td>
                <td>@employee.Address</td>
                <td>@employee.City</td>
                <td>@employee.RoleID</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

And my create view looks like this:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@model DiplomskiProjektDrugi_Client.ViewModels.EmpManViewModel

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>CreateEmp</title>
</head>
<body>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateEmp", "EmpMan"))
    {
        <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Employee.Name)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Employee.NAme)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Employee.LastName)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Employee.LastName)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Employee.Address)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Employee.Address)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Employee.City)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Employee.City)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Employee.RoleID)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Employee.RoleID)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Save"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }

</body>
</html>
```

After starting it I get to the index page, which contains a list of all the employees from the database and a "Add new employee" button. Pressing the button I get to a page where I can enter data for the new employee (Name,LastName,Address,City and RoleID). After I enter data and press save, it returns me to the index page, but the data I have entered is not saved. There is no exception or a error. I really don't know why this is happening.

Comment: where is the code that makes databse operations? In case of Entity framework where is **<DbContext>** class?

Comment: @Aravind Sorry, but I think I asked the question in a wrong way because I don't have a <DbContext> class. I'm really new to this so please understand if I don't explain it the right way immediately.I have a Wcf service that does CRUD operations on the database using the Entity Data Model.CreateEmp method in the Wcf service creates a new employee in EmployeeTable.I call the service from the client and I can normaly input data (CreateEmp view). After inputing everything I press save and it takes me back to IndexEmp view where I see that nothing is saved in the database.